# Repeating character for divider line in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-4.0

This is just a question of curiosity to better learn how PowerShell works.  Why can I put the repeating string into a variable, but not put it in a Write-Host statement? The purpose is to print a row of dashes as a divider.

```
$divider = "-"*25
Write-Host $divider 
Write-Host "-"*25
Write-Host $("-"*25)  #is this the best way to do it with a var?
```

Results Window:

```
-------------------------
- *25
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In, Write-Host "-"*25, it is evaluated as an **argument** to the function instead of an expression. So, parenthesis need to be used to get it as an expression first and then result of this expression passed as an argument to Write-Host.

Check the [about Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1)